# Are all objects Immutable inside Heap?

Tags: c#, heap-memory, immutability

Given,

```
public class SomeClass {
     public string SomeName{get;}
     public List<string> RelatedNames{get;}
}

public class Program{
     public void Main(){
          var someClassInstance = new SomeClass(){ SomeName = "A", RelatedNames = new List<string>(1){ "a" }};
          // So, now someClassInstance have been allocated some memory in heap = 1 string object and a list with 1 string object.

          // Since SomeClass is mutable, it could be modified as below
          someClassInstance.SomeName = "Now This is much more than a name";
          someClassInstance.RelatedNames = someClassInstance.RelatedNames.AddRange(new List<string>(100} { "N","o","w".....});

         //Now what happens inside heap?
         //1.someClassInstance.SomeName will move it's pointer to another string inside heap
         //2.someClassInstance.RealtedNames will move it's pointer to another List<>(101) inside heap.
         //Is it correct? Then where is 'mutability' ?
     }
}
```

As mentioned in the comments above, "AFAIK" on modifying a mutable object the internal pointers of that object will just point to another memory location inside heap. If that is correct, then does that mean that all objects inside heap (reference type) are immutable?

Thanks for your interest.

Comment: "The internal pointers of that object will just point to another memory location", i.e., will be mutated. So ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where's mutability? Right there:

```
someClassInstance.SomeName = "Now This is much more than a name";
someClassInstance.RelatedNames = new List<string>(100} { "N","o","w".....};
```

You just *mutated* the object pointed to by `someClassInstance`.

Also, your example is a bit contrived. `String`s are indeed immutable, but `List`s are not, so you could have done this:

```
someClassInstance.RelatedNames.Add("HELLO!");
```

And then you just mutated the object pointed to by `someClassInstance.RelatedNames`.

---

EDIT: I see you changed your question. Well, then:

> 1. someClassInstance.SomeName will move it's pointer to another string inside heap
> 2. someClassInstance.RealtedNames will move it's pointer to another List<>(101) inside heap.

`1` is true because `String` was *designed* to be immutable. That's why there's the `StringBuilder` class in case you need a mutable string.

`2` is false, because that's not how `List` is implemented. Perhaps that's where your confusion comes from. Still, when you invoke `AddRange`, `someClassInstance.RelatedNames` will still point to the same instance, but that instance's internal state will have changed (most likely, its backing array will have been changed to point to a different array object, and its count would now be `101`). In fact, a reference cannot magically change based on the operations that are invoked to the object it refers to.

And none of that changes the fact that `someClassInstance`'s internal state was mutated anyway.

Comment: I agree about the RelatedNames.Add suggestion, modified OP. But in this case also it is going to point to new location, right?

Comment: "And then you just mutated the object pointed to by someClassInstance.RelatedNames" - this won't happen because I have explicitly set the List size = 1. And adding a new object would require a fresh memory allocation for a new List. So, what is mutated here?

Comment: +1: "most likely, its backing array will have been changed to point to a different array object," - I was actually ignoring the internals of List. Thanks, you answered my query.

Answer (score 1):

Object in the CLR are definitely not immutable by default.  There is a little bit of confusion here because you've used `string` in your example which is a type that's implemented as an immutable type.  This is certainly not the default in .Net though and mutability is far more common than immutability.

Take this line as an example

```
someClassInstance.SomeName = "Now This is much more than a name";
```

There are 3 objects of interest here in this statement.

- The object referenced by `someClassInstance.SomeName`
- The string which has the value `"Now this is much more than a name"`
- The object referenced by 'someClassInstance`

All 3 of these values live in the heap.  The execution of this statement will mutate the contents of the object referenced by `someClassInstance`.  This is a prime example of mutability in action.  If everything in this scenario were immutable then the settnig of `SomeName` would need to produce a copy of the object referenced by `someClassInstance` and give it the new value.  This doesn't happen here and can be demonstrated by the following

```
var obj = someClassInstance;  // Both reference the same object
someClassInstance.SomeName = "hello";
Console.WriteLine(someClassInstance.SomeName): // Prints "hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes because they are put on the heap using new or malloc and are pointers.  As such you can only add or remove pointer references.  So technically the objects themselves are not immutable, since they are not on the heap to begin with, but the pointer allocations on the heap are immutable.

Comment: Can you please clarify - "technically the objects themselves are not immutable, since they are not on the heap to begin with" ?

Comment: edit (pooly formatted)...The object itself is not on the heap, on the pointer to the object is on the heap.  So pointer in heap, object not in heap.

Comment: @JJJ The object is on the CLR's heap. References are stored either on the heap (when they're fields of objects) or on the stack (when they're local variables).

Comment: What is this thing you call "malloc"?

Comment: @Eric Yeah, I was wondering too what is `malloc` doing in a discussion about C#.